# »Vergiss nicht den Reisepass« oder »Vergiss den Reisepass nicht«?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, negation, imperative

Welcher Satz ist richtig?

> - Vergiss nicht den Reisepass.
> - Vergiss den Reisepass nicht.

Comment: Beide sind richtig und heißen dasselbe

Comment: Oder `Den Reisepass nicht vergessen!` oder `Nicht den Reisepass vergessen.` Oft tut es aber auch der Personalausweis. ;)

Comment: Ich empfehle dringend die Lektüre von [Das grammatische Varieté oder die Kunst und das Vergnügen, deutsche Sätze zu bilden](https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?referrer=Wikipedia&method=simpleSearch&query=3821840749).

Comment: Um mit Karl Valentin zu sprechen: "Vergiss nicht die Kommode im Flur!" - "Warum?" - "Weil da der Reisepass draufliegt"

Answer (score 10):

Beide sind korrekt - mit dem Unterschied, dass im ersten Fall die Betonung ein wenig mehr auf dem Gegenstand liegt, der nicht vergessen werden soll; es ist aber wirklich nur eine Akzentverschiebung.

Answer (score 7):

Zur Stellung von *"nicht"* als nicht-kontrastierende Verneinung finden wir folgende Regel:

> Wenn nicht als nicht kontrastierende, pauschale Verneinung verwendet wird, hat es die Tendenz weit hinten im Satz zu stehen.<sup>[Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Negation/Stellung/nichtkontrast.html?MenuId=Sentence730)</sup>

Diese Regel wird im aufgeführten Beispiel eingehalten:

> Vergiss den Reisepass nicht.

Stellt man das nicht vor den Reisepass, so leitet man dadurch entweder einen Nebensatz ein:

> - Vergiss nicht, den Reisepass einzupacken.

oder man hebt durch *"nicht"* in [kontrastierender Verneinung](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Negation/Stellung/kontrast.html?MenuId=Sentence731) einen Satzteil hervor:

> - Wir haben nicht den Reisepass, sondern das Geld vergessen.

Beides kommt aber in dem genannten Beispiel nicht vor, so dass die Formulierung *"Vergiss nicht den Reisepass"* unvollständig erscheint, wohl aber umgangssprachlich nicht selten angetroffen wird.

Answer (score 3):

Im ersten Fall wird genau genommen der Reisepass negiert, im zweiten das Vergessen. Das merkt man, wenn man unsinnige Fälle konstruiert, in denen es auf den Unterschied ankommt:

- Vergiss nicht den Reisepass, sondern das Flugticket.
- Vergiss den Reisepass nicht, sondern lass ihn absichtlich zu Hause liegen.

Anders herum klingt es gestelzt:

- (unnatürlich) Vergiss den Reisepass nicht, sondern das Flugticket.
- (unnatürlich) Vergiss nicht den Reisepass, sondern lass ihn absichtlich zu Hause liegen.

Das ist in beiden Fällen eine ungewöhnliche und auffällige Wortstellung. (Es mag verwirrend erscheinen, dass die Negation des Verbs hinter dem Objekt erfolgt. Grund ist, dass die Negation Teil der Verbgruppe ist und diese mit Ausnahme eines einzigen Worts, des einzelnen konjugierten Verbs, im normalen Hauptsatz immer am Ende kommt. Beispiel: "Ich **habe** den Reisepass **nicht vergessen**." Wenn die Verbgruppe nur aus dem konjugierten Verb und *nicht* besteht, steht *nicht* am Ende des Satzes zufällig allein.)

Wahrscheinlich ist mit dem Satz eine komplette Verneinung von *den Reisepass vergessen* gemeint. Anders als im Englischen erfolgt die Verneinung eines Verbs samt Objekt (direkt oder indirekt) im Deutschen nicht zwangsläufig durch Verneinung des Verbs, sondern man kann statt dessen auch das Objekt verneinen.

Besonders groß ist der Unterschied zum Englischen, wenn das Objekt einen unbestimmten Artikel trägt. Um *einen Reisepass vergessen* zu verneinen, muss man das Objekt verneinen und muss es mit *keinen* tun:

- Vergiss keinen Reisepass. (In der Familie hat jeder einen Pass. Sie werden alle gebraucht.)

Wenn man *nicht einen* benutzt, verneint man den unbestimmten Artikel, den man in diesem Fall eher als Zahlwort auffasst:

- Vergiss nicht einen Reisepass, sondern zwei.

Wenn man das Verb verneint, ändert sich der Sinn des Satzes ebenfalls:

- Vergiss einen Reisepass nicht. Was du mit dem anderen machst, ist egal. (Der Reisende hat selbst mehr als einen Pass.)

Letzteres würde man meistens anders ausdrücken, aber wenn man auf diese Weise verneint, dann fällt die Unbestimmtheit von *einen* jedenfalls nicht mit unter die Negation.